# How to distribute events to specific group of partitions

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I want my two client applications share one Event hubs but use different partitions, say, if the event hubs has 16 partitions, events from app 1 will always be distributed to partition 1 - 7, and events from app 2 will always be distributed to partition 8 - 16.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

This could be implemented. As I know, Event hub sdk supports sending to specific partition. But this is not a good practice. You should use two event hub separately.